# C# Expand Dictionary or Hashtable to include Pop and Push (LIFO)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dictionary, stack

Looking for structure that contains the benefits of a stack but the ability to only contain one item that matches a key.

For example
Data comes in from various clients, I am only interested in the last piece of data from a particular client. So a dictionary would work very well. However I want to process the data from all the clients in a LIFO scenario, so a stack would be best.

Any ideas on combining the two?

Comment: Hold`Stack` for each client, I see that suits for your case.

Comment: Are you asking for permission to try to combine stack and hastable into single data structure? Not really sure what exact problem you have with your suggestion...

Comment: Was looking for sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to interpret what you want.  For instance when you `Push` a value with a key which already exists, what happens?

1. Existing item is popped, new one pushed,
2. Replace value for the existing item with the new data
3. Exception

If the LIFO aspect is the key consideration, you mainly need a modified `Stack` to associate a key with the data. A `LinkedList` would be another alternative.

`Push`/`Pop` on a `List` would require implementing it as `Insert(0)` and `RemoveAt(0)`.  This means the underlying array would be *rebuilt for each and every operation*.  A `Stack` works inversely: new items are stored at the *end* of the array so it only has to be rebuilt periodically.

Depending on the size and amount of data, that may not matter.

In mentioning `Dictionary` it becomes unclear if you also want access by key; that is, you can `Pop` items, but also retrieve them by key.  That seems at odds with the nature of a `Stack`.  First, a class to associate a Key (name) with an item:

```vb
Class NameValuePair(Of T)
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Value As T

    Public Sub New(n As String, v As T)
        Name = n
        Value = v
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(n As String)
        Name = n
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("{0} ({1})", Name, Value.ToString)
    End Function
End Class
```

Then the stack-like collection.  This will surely need work depending on the answers to the above and other unknowns.  If the data size is small, I might stick with a `List` just for simplicity.

```vb
Public Class KeyedStack(Of T)
    Private myStack As Stack(Of NameValuePair(Of T))

    Public Sub New()
        myStack = New Stack(Of NameValuePair(Of T))
    End Sub

    Public Sub Push(key As String, value As T)
        Dim item = myStack.FirstOrDefault(Function(k) String.Compare(k.Name, key, True) = 0)
        If item IsNot Nothing Then
            ' replace
            item.Value = value
        Else
            myStack.Push(New NameValuePair(Of T)(key, value))
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function Pop() As T
        ' todo check count
        Dim item = myStack.Pop
        Return item.Value
    End Function

    Public Function Peek() As T
        Return myStack.Peek().Value
    End Function

    ' ToDo: add Count, Contains, ContainsKey as needed
End Class
```

The keys are case-insensitive.  The base `Stack` provides the ordering, while the `NameValuePair` provides the dictionary-like key.

If you needed `Push` to treat dupes as new items (they loose their old place):

```vb
' replace item as new
Public Sub PushAsNew(key As String, value As T)
    Dim tmp = myStack.ToList()
    Dim ndx = tmp.FindIndex(Function(k) String.Compare(k.Name, key, True) = 0)

    If ndx > -1 Then
        tmp.RemoveAt(ndx)
        myStack = New Stack(Of NameValuePair(Of T))(tmp.ToArray.Reverse)
    End If

    myStack.Push(New NameValuePair(Of T)(key, value))
End Sub
```

Since `Stack` items are not meant to be removed by index, it becomes pretty expensive to do so (stack to list to array to reversed array to new stack).  A `PopByKey` method is equally expensive.  Hopefully, you wont need it.  Ulta simple testing:

```vb
Dim data = {"Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta", "Echo", "Ziggy"}
Dim stacker = New KeyedStack(Of String)

For Each s As String In data
    stacker.Push(s(0), s)
Next
' result == Z, E, D, G, B, A order

stacker.Push("a", "Apple")
' item(5) is now {A, Apple} (key case ignored)

Dim item = stacker.Pop
' item == "Ziggy"

item = stacker.PopKey("g")
' new contents ==  E, D, B, A 
' item == "Gamma"

stacker.PushAsNew("B", "Bottle")
' new contents ==  B, E, D, A
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want something that would be called `HashStack<T>`.

`T` would need to implement `IEquatable<T>` or override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, or you can accept an `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

If you don't want to overcomplicate things, you'll need to implement `IList<T>` with `Push` method. The `Add` method will be called by `Push` and it'll need to evaluate if the item to be added is already in the stack by either calling item's `GetHashCode`/`Equals` or you can also maintain an internal `HashSet<T>` to optimize this check that has already implemented equality check (`HashSet<T>.Add` will return `false` if the item is already in the set...).

Items would need to be also stored in an internal `List<T>` to being able to get *last item* by insertion order.

Comment: Thanks,Will give it a try, do you have sample code by any chance?

Comment: @Wize No, you'll need to do it from scratch :\

Comment: @Wize BTW you should expect few code lines for this