# How can I dequeue an item at certain index in a queue of string?

Tags: vb.net, queue

I am trying to dequeue items if they contain a certain string. This is the idea I was hoping would work but does not:

```
Dim baseUri As String = myuri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)
        For i = workerURLs.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If workerURLs(i).Contains(baseUri) Then
                workerURLs.Dequeue(i)
            End If
        Next
```

Since the queue method has no "Dequeue at index" option like a list would how can I accomplish this?

Comment: That's not how a `Queue` works. You'll want to use a `List` instead if you want to manipulate the collection at arbitrary indexes.

Comment: The queue is constantly being checked by background workers and is quite long. Basically what I am trying to accomplish is users being able to dequeue large chunks of the queued strings at runtime while the background workers are accessing the queue. If I were to convert the queue to list, filter it, then set the queue as that list I feel like that would cause issues. Maybe what I am trying to accomplish is not possible or not a good idea at all.

Comment: @ZachJohnson it sounds like you need an hybrid collection, such peculiar implementation doesn't exist in the framework, but you can easily implement it yourself. Easiest way (not the cleanest) is to inherit the Queue<T> and when queueing data you also add them to an indexable collection and create an overload of the Dequeue method...

Comment: I will look into that thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If you need to remove items from random locations, which is it a queue at all?  There are other alternatives that may work better.  For one type of hybrid see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35484887/1070452

Comment: You could be right. In learning about background worker pools this is the way it was done in the example. Using a sync locked queue. Admittedly I never looked into what the queue actually did or its true purpose. If I can switch to a list of string instead of queue I gladly would maybe thats all that needs to be done..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to implement it would be to wrap a `Queue(Of T)` and recreate it when an element gets "dequeued" from the middle:

```
Class IndexableQueue(Of T)

    Private _queue As New Queue(Of T)()

    Public Sub Enqueue(item As T)
        _queue.Enqueue(item)
    End Sub

    Public Function Dequeue() As T
        Return _queue.Dequeue()
    End Function

    Public Function Dequeue(index As Integer) As T
        Dim list = _queue.ToList()

        Dim item = list(index)

        list.RemoveAt(index)

        _queue = New Queue(Of T)(list)

        Return item
    End Function

End Class
```

This is the simplest implementation although it's not the most efficient as we are recreating the `Queue` on every call to `Dequeue(Integer)`. But if it's uncommon and the queue is not massive it should be fine.

The best way would be to completely reimplement the `Queue` and use a `List` instead of an array as underlying type.